# text-wrapping program in c does not work correctly

Tags: c, word-wrap, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm following K & R. At the end of chapter 1, one of the proposed exercises is about writing a text wrapping program. Here's the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
#define WRAP 10

int getl(char s[]);
void wrap(char s[], int l);

/* wrap.c: wraps text */
main ()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int c;

    while ((c = getl(line)) >= 0)
        wrap(line, c);
    return 0;
}

int getl(char s[])
{
    int i, c;

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && i < MAXLINE; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    s[i] = '\n';
    if (c == EOF)
        i = -1;
    return i;
}

void wrap(char s[], int l)
{
    int i = 1,ii, c;

    if (l == 0)
        putchar('\n');
    for(c = 0; s[i-1] != '\n'; c = c + i)
    {
        if (l - c <= WRAP)
            for (i = c; i <= l; ++i)
                putchar(s[i]);
        else
        {
            for (i = c + WRAP - 1; i >= c && s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t'; --i)
                ;
            if (i == (c-1))
            {
                for (i = c + WRAP; s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t' && s[i] != '\n'; ++i)
                    ;
                for (ii = c; ii < i; ++ii)
                    putchar(s[ii]);
                putchar('\n');
                if (s[i] != '\n')
                    ++i;
            }
            else if (i == c)
                ++i;
            else
            {
                for (ii = c; ii < i; ++ii)
                    putchar(s[ii]);
                putchar('\n');
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a file called wraptest which includes the following:

```
asd

asdf
asd fg

asdflkjasdad sasdf
adsfa asdfasfd adfsdf
asd asdfadfasdfad
this line
```

when running

```
./wrap < wraptest
```

I get the following

```
asd

asdf
asd fg

asdflkjasdad
sasdf
adsfa
asdfasfd

asd
asdfadfasdfad
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Valgrind gives me the following:

```
==6729== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6729==    at 0x80486EE: wrap (wrap.c:37)
==6729==    by 0x80484CC: main (wrap.c:15)
==6729==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation  
==6729==    at 0x80484A2: main (wrap.c:10)
==6729== 
==6729== Invalid read of size 1 
==6729==    at 0x80486E9: wrap (wrap.c:37)
==6729==    by 0x80484CC: main (wrap.c:15)
==6729==  Address 0xbe8a3623 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6729== 
==6729== 
==6729== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6729==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xBE8A3623
==6729==    at 0x80486E9: wrap (wrap.c:37)
==6729==    by 0x80484CC: main (wrap.c:15)
==6729==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6729==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6729==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6729==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6729==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6729== 
==6729== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6729==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6729==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==6729== 
==6729== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6729== 
==6729== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6729== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So what's the error? I've been searching for about an hour but I haven't found it.

Comment: `s[i] = '\n';` in `getl` can lead to an off-by-one overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never checking the value of `i`, yet it is indexing into your string array in the `wrap` function.  Here is where the `i` value grows into the 1000's on my machine before crashing.  I would recommend putting it on a debugger, simplifying your code, or at least check the variable that indexes into your string buffer to ensure it is not past the end of the buffer.  HTH!

**EDIT**

Since you asked, I'll show you how I debugged this, just a little, on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

From the shell, file called `sotest.c`

```
# use the -g for debug info
gcc -g sotest.c -o sotest
# invoke the gnu debugger
gdb sotest
```

You'll see:

> GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04 Copyright
>   (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL
>   version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free
>   software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO
>   WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and
>   "show warranty" for details. This GDB was configured as
>   "i686-linux-gnu". For bug reporting instructions, please see:
>   http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/... Reading symbols from
>   /home/macduff/sotest...done.
>   (gdb)

Then, invoke the program with the input file:

```
run < wraptest
```

Then you'll get some output text with the stack trace

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x08048666 in
>   wrap (
>       s=0xbfffebd4 "asd\n\030\313\375\267\254|\376\267\f\356\377\277", l=3)
>       at sotest.c:58 58             for (i = c + WRAP - 1; i >= c && s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t'; --i)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using linux and compiling in the command line with gcc. Do you know a good debugger I can use? Or does gcc already include one?

Comment: Finally found the problem. The line: `if (s[i] != '\n')` in `wrap()` causes all the trouble and shouldn't exist.